# Сравнение двух массивов и вывод одинаковых значений

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, затупил на этой задаче
Даны две строки строчных латинских символов: строка J и строка S. Символы, входящие в строку J, — «драгоценности», входящие в строку S — «камни». Нужно определить, какое количество символов из S одновременно являются «драгоценностями». Проще говоря, нужно проверить, какое количество символов из S входит в J.

```
Ввод    Вывод  
ab      4  
aabbccd
```

Попытался сделать код через регулярки получилось не совсем то, данный код ищет лишь одинаковые значения

```
document.write(("this is foo bar".match(/o/g)||[]).length);
```

не подскажете как сравнить 2 строки и вывести только одинаковые значения у обеих. может я забыл метод в джаваскрипте, который отвечает за это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как то так

```
const j='драгоценности';
const s='камни';

console.log(s.split('').filter(char => j.includes(char)).join(''));
```

Comment: о!точно,спасибо мужик!

Comment: а то я пытался уже сделать сравнение через двойной цикл

Comment: что то типа этого пилил
var charRepeats = function(str) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i+1; j <= str.length; j++) {
            if(str[j] == str[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: Автор вопроса может пометить один из ответов «принятым» :)